# How can I clear the terminal in my Ruby console utility?

Tags: ruby, shell

I'm trying to write a little console script in Ruby that will run my tests for me. I'm basing it on [this Rake task](https://gist.github.com/peterc/113226) by Peter Cooper.

It works, but it would be nice if it would clear the console before each run.

Can someone tell me how to make it do that?

Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'find'
files = {}

session_count = 0

puts "Watching #{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}."

loop do
  changed = false
  Find.find(File.dirname(__FILE__)) do |file|
    next unless file =~ /\.rb$/
    ctime = File.ctime(file).to_i

    if ctime != files[file]
      files[file] = ctime
      changed = true
    end
  end

  if changed

    command = 'ruby -Itest test/**/*_test.rb'

    puts '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    puts "[#{session_count}] #### Running:\n      #{command}"
    puts '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -'

    puts `#{command}`

    puts '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    puts "[#{session_count}] #### Done"
    puts '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

    session_count += 1

  end

  sleep 1
end
```

I'm on Mac OS 10.7.5 and using Zsh 4.3.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
 if changed
    system('clear') 
...
```